# Formatting attributes on the same line in editor config

Tags: c#, editorconfig

Is there any option on editor config to format attributes like in "Example1" instead of "Example2"?

The example below is C#.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK there is no such option for "vanilla" .editorconfig, but if you are using Rider/Resharper then there are quite a lot of options to [setup arrangement of attributes﻿](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/EditorConfig_CSHARP_LineBreaksPageSchema.html#Arrangement_of_attributes). For example you can use the following:

```
[*.cs]
place_attribute_on_same_line = false
```

Or to target specifically fields:

```
[*.cs]
csharp_place_field_attribute_on_same_line = false
```